# Why does BigInteger.ToString("x") prepend a 0 for values between signed.MaxValue (exclusive) and unsigned.MaxValue (inclusive)?

Tags: c#, biginteger

Examples (asterisks next to odd behavior):

```
    [Fact]
    public void BigInteger_ToString_behavior_is_odd()
    {
        writeHex(new BigInteger(short.MaxValue)); // 7fff
        writeHex(new BigInteger(short.MaxValue) + 1); // 08000 **
        writeHex(new BigInteger(ushort.MaxValue)); // 0ffff **
        writeHex(new BigInteger(ushort.MaxValue) + 1); // 10000

        writeHex(new BigInteger(int.MaxValue)); // 7fffffff
        writeHex(new BigInteger(int.MaxValue) + 1); // 080000000 **
        writeHex(new BigInteger(uint.MaxValue)); // 0ffffffff **
        writeHex(new BigInteger(uint.MaxValue) + 1); // 100000000

        writeHex(new BigInteger(long.MaxValue)); // 7fffffffffffffff
        writeHex(new BigInteger(long.MaxValue) + 1); // 08000000000000000 **
        writeHex(new BigInteger(ulong.MaxValue)); // 0ffffffffffffffff **
        writeHex(new BigInteger(ulong.MaxValue) + 1); // 10000000000000000
    }

    private static void writeHex(BigInteger value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("x"));
    }
```

- Is there a reason for this?
- How would I remove this extra zero?  Can I just check if the string has a zero at the start and, if so, remove it?  Any corner cases to think about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without a leading zero, the number may appear as though it is a *negative* number of the same number of bits in two's complement. Putting a leading zero ensures that the high bit isn't set, so it can't possibly be interpreted as a negative number.

Go ahead and remove the first character, if it's a zero, unless it's the only character in the string.

Comment: It is odd though since it seems like a well thought design choise, but it isn't documented as far as I could find. (not saying that you are not right though)

Comment: So to be extremely specific: Whenever the number is positive and the most significant hex digit is between `8` and `F` (incl.), they have to prepend one `0`. In an entirely similar way, they sometimes have to prepend an `F` to negative hex numbers, to make sure they don't look positive.

Answer (score 1):

From my part not sure why this is done, but as you mentioned converting to string and then removing leading zero should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `BigInteger` with the `x` format specifier wants to write out a byte at a time.

See this example:

```
writeHex(new BigInteger(15));
```

> 0f

As such, feel free to remove any padded `'0'` at the beginning:

```
private static void writeHex(BigInteger value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("x").TrimStart('0'));
}
```

> Is there a reason for this?

A good reason for them to implement it this way is that it is still correct, and probably performs better in the tight loop they use to implement `ToString` (avoiding branches).

From reflector, the implementation looks like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
byte[] buffer = value.ToByteArray();

// ... A bunch of pre-amble for special cases here,
// though obviously not including the high byte being < 0x10.  Then:

while (index > -1)
{
    builder.Append(buffer[index--].ToString(str, info));
}
```

**Edit**:

Well, Ben brought up a good point.  Some of those examples you gave output an odd number of nibbles, so I guess the implementation is just quirky :)

You can still use the `string.TrimStart` function to get around that problem.

Comment: If `value` is zero, won't that print an empty line?

Comment: That's not it, it's actually writing out an ODD number of hex digits (4-bit nibbles).

Comment: @Ben: Oh, you're right.  I missed the other cases.  I guess it's just quirky then ;)

Answer (score 1):

IMO positive values should include a leading zero and i believe that is why you see those in your outputs.

To avoid maybe you could specify a specific formatting for the output

Answer (score 0):

**No reason?**!

Perhaps this is simply just a quirck! Remember, the base class libraries were developed by developers, i.e. humans! You can expect the odd quirck to creep into them.

Answer (score 0):

It might be interesting to note that the `byte[]` returned by the method `ToByteArray` also contains a leading zero byte in your example cases.

So, to answer your question literally, your examples are formatted with a leading zero because the byte array representing the number contains a leading zero and it's that array that's spit out in hexadecimal.

Comment: If this was the reason then there would always be an even number of hex digits in the output.

Comment: @finnw: I think you've misunderstood. In the cases where a leading zero is produced in the hex output, the byte array also contains a leading zero.  I.e. `(new BigInteger(ushort.MaxValue)).ToByteArray()` produces the array `{0xFF,0xFF,0}`.  Such an array would be printed with 5 hexadecimal digits, because the private method `FormatBigIntegerToHexString`, ultimately used for the hex format specifier, loops through the array backwards and prints each element.  It has a special case for the first byte encountered that allows for 1 or 2 digits.