# C# BigInteger bitwise XOR returning extra digit

Tags: c#

I am trying to perform xor operation on two hex string via BigInteger. Output is returning one extra '0'

"FB7E412203248EB9" ^ "1234560000000000" = E94A172203248EB9

But I am getting  0E94A172203248EB9

```
BigInteger output = BigInteger.Parse("00" + "FB7E412203248EB9", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber) ^ BigInteger.Parse("00" + "1234560000000000", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

string strOutput = output.ToString("X");
```

Expected Result: E94A172203248EB9

Actual Result:   0E94A172203248EB9

Comment: remove the `"00" + `. You are not doing `"FB7E412203248EB9" ^ "1234560000000000"`, you are doing `"00FB7E412203248EB9" ^ "001234560000000000"`

Comment: @Cid Which gives a completely different intermediate value in `output`.

Comment: @Safee Note all the info about XOR etc. isn't needed here, you could replace the first line of code with `var output = BigInteger.Parse("16810273993962852025");`

Comment: @DavidG I misread your comment - I thought it was parsing as hex, but it's parsing as decimal.

Comment: Leading zero is here for sign disembiguation in BigInteger representation; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6248161/1507014) for example. Remember that BigInteger is a signed infinite-sized integer; your result is positive as an operation over two positive integers and begin with 'E', so it must display a leading 0 to keep the result positive in its representation as a string.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's not a bug, it's to prevent the number being interpreted as a negative value - see the linked dupe.